# installing sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have been asked to look in to Sharepoint, I'm currently on a mac but I have a window's pc which i can access, what do I need to be able to install Sharepoint and play around with it?? Thanks

Comment: ask microsoft, they'll be happy to tell you: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/

Comment: You need quite a lot to install SharePoint and "play around", and you didn't mention if you need to develop or just use out-of-the-box features. Anyway, there should be a image you can download (of a virtual SharePoint server)

Comment: When I installed 2010 for a dev image I used the following links: they might be useful for you:
http://andreasglaser.net/post/2009/11/17/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2-and-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Part-1-Overview.aspx
-----------------------
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2007, you need Windows Server 2003 (R2) or 2008 (R2), both 32 and 64 bit are supported. SharePoint 2010 only runs on Windows Server 2008 (R2) 64 bit.

If you plan to run SharePoint 2010 in a virtual machine, make sure you have a powerful machine (preferably quadcore) with lots of memory and a fast harddisk.

More info on 2010 hardware requirements: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx

For development/evaluation purposes, you could also install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: +1
I want to add: in practice, we used x64 2 core computers with 4 gigs of memory with Windows 7 for SharePoint Foundation 2010, and I think it is the actual minimum, because 2 gigs RAM were causing some strange errors.